# Security in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs

I am new to Extjs. My question is if  I have to communicate to Server and get records from database. How can I secure my Ajax or rest calls as every communication to server is done via ajax or Rest. Is SSL is the only way to secure our ajax/ rest calls to server?

Comment: What technology are you using for backend web service? For instance, in IIS with C# web services you can enable windows authentication for communication.  I think it could depend on your backend.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the nature of your application, but HTTPS is best practice when transferring any sensitive information to a remote web server such as a password or session token. OAuth 1 or 2 is probably the way to go.

This link describes different options https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/

Also, to save yourself time, you may want to consider using a platform like DreamFactory to provide a REST API interface for your SQL/No-SQL database. This provides user session management and saves you the extra effort of coding your own REST API.